# rootElement.appendChild(childElement) after xml comment

Tags: java, xml

I have comments in my xml file, call it X. I am taking from another xml file, Y, and I want place the Elements under the correct comments in X. I am using the java appendChild method. The "rootElement" in this case will be dependencies. It is placing the childElement at the bottom of the rootElement tag in X. Is it possible to do this?

```
<dependencies defaultconf="compile" defaultconfmapping="*-&gt;default">
    <!--COMPILE-->
    <!-- Compile dependencies are available in all classpaths of a project. -->
    <!-- These dependencies are included in the war's WEB-INF/lib and are propagated to     dependent projects. -->
    <!-- This is the default config and is used if no config is specified. -->

    <!--PROVIDED-->`
    <!-- This is much like compile, but indicates you expect the JDK or the tomcat container to provide the dependency at runtime. -->
    <!-- This scope is only available on the compilation and test classpaths, and is not transitive. -->
    <!-- NOTE: You must add conf="provided" to the dependency -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Assuming you're using a library that supports DOM methods (you're using `appendChild`, so I'm guessing you are), you can use [`insertBefore`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-952280727) rather than `appendChild`, using the [`nextSibling`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-6AC54C2F) property of the element you want to put it after.

For instance, if `theCommentNode` is the node you want to put `newStuff` after, then:

```
theCommentNode.parentNode.insertBefore(newStuff, theCommentNode.nextSibling);
```

(`theCommentNode.parentNode` is presumably `rootElement`, from your quoted XML.)

If `nextSibling` is `null`, that will append at the end; if not, it will put `newStuff` between `theCommentNode` and what used to be its immediate next sibling.